# Factory class - stop init

Tags: ios, objective-c, factory-pattern

I want to create a factory class to create objects for me (of a specific class).

The Factory class will just have class methods. Is there a way I can stop alloc init from being called on the class?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to make sure it is never actually instanciated? If so then overwite alloc and init, don't call any superclass' alloc and init and return nil. But why? An 'empty' class does not cost many bytes of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, define init at you interface as

```
- (id) init __unavailable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return `self` in alloc and init. `self` in this case means class object, so calling method on this object will cause calling class methods

```
+ (id)alloc {
    return (id)self;
}

+ (id)init {
    return self;
}
```

Comment: `self` in ' init'  should carry the object, not the class? What you say is true for  `alloc`. So in `init` `[self class]` should be returned.

Comment: If you return class object in `alloc`? In `init` self will be object that your return in `alloc`, I guess

Comment: Well, that would work on runtime. On compile time this would throw a number of warnings and when using ARC even errors. Or it requires all the class methods to be declared (interface should do) as both, class and instance method.

Comment: + (id)alloc {
    return (id)self;
}

- (id)init {
    return self;
}
Check it.

Comment: Yes, could work. 'Class' is an object at last. So it can be casted to (id). Are you sure that the instance method -init is called and not a class mehtod +init? Next question would be, if the caller calls a method abc, which woud that be. -abc or +abc?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it will be `+init` and on class object it always would be +. But topic starter wants class methods from the beginning